# MySQL concatenate data from multiple columns skipping dups

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a way to group duplicate column data.
I have a table with data like:

```
-------------------------------------------
ID  | locationId | day | open     | close
-------------------------------------------
1   | 1213       | Wed | 10:00 am | 4:30 pm
-------------------------------------------
2   | 1213       | Thr | 10:00 am | 4:30 pm
-------------------------------------------
3   | 1213       | Fri | 10:00 am | 4:30 pm
-------------------------------------------
4   | 1213       | Sat | 10:00 am | 5:30 pm
-------------------------------------------
```

I am using `group_concat` to return the information for locationId 1213 as

`Wed: 10:00 am-04:30 pm,Thu: 10:00 am-04:30 pm,Fri: 10:00 am-04:30 pm,Sat: 10:00 am-05:30 pm`

Is there a way to use group_concat or another function/query to group the duplicate open and close times and return the data similar to the following?

```
Wed,Thr,Fri: 10:00 am-04:30 pm,Sat: 10:00 am-05:30 pm
```

or even

```
Wed-Fri: 10:00 am-04:30 pm,Sat: 10:00 am-05:30 pm
```

Below is the SQL code that I am using:

```
SELECT appdata.nameShort, 
group_concat(distinct concat(appdatahours.`day`,": ", appdatahours.open, "-", 
appdatahours.close)) as hours
FROM appdata
LEFT JOIN appdatalocations on appdatalocations.listingId = appdata.id
LEFT JOIN appdatahours on appdatahours.locationId = appdatalocations.id
GROUP BY appdata.id
```

Comment: in that case you will have subquery on a subquery, thus causing poor performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (uses a derived table):

```
select locationId, group_concat(day_group) from
(
    SELECT
    locationID, concat(group_concat(`day`),": ", open, "-", close) as day_group
    FROM tableB
    GROUP BY locationID, open, close
) dayGroup;
```

sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c19c5/1/0

Comment: This works great! Thank you. I figured out how to use your suggestion with a join:


`SELECT appdata.id,appdata.nameShort, locationId, group_concat(day_group) as hours
FROM appdata
LEFT JOIN appdatalocations on appdatalocations.listingId = appdata.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    locationID, concat(group_concat(`day`),": ", `open`, "-", `close`) as day_group
    FROM appdatahours
    GROUP BY locationID, `open`, `close`
    ORDER BY id
) dayGroup on dayGroup.locationId = appdatalocations.id
GROUP BY appdata.id, locationId
order by appdata.id`